# React Native Login to Home Screen navigation

Tags: react-native, authentication, navigation, stack-navigator

I'm new to React Native, and want to build a login page that connects to the home page, but if I use a single stack navigator, I get the little arrow in the top lefthand corner that just allows the user to go back to the login page without clicking on the logout button, which wouldn't log them out correctly. How can I make it so that arrow goes away on the Home Screen? Do I need to make 2 stack navigators and link them together somehow? I don't have any code written yet, I'm just looking for a general explanation before I get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the documentation of **React Navigation authentication flow**
according to the documentation Don't manually navigate when conditionally rendering screens between Auth and Home screens.

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
);
```

[Full documentation of React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, need to set "headerLeft" to null in the Stack Screen

Comment: That will not be a permanent solution. If you click android back button it will again go the login page. You can follow the Suggestion of @ABDULLAH to check the authentication and render your stack conditionally.